# Unable to Solve a quiz question asked in mathematics exam ( Quantitative Aptitude)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am self studying for an exam and I am unable to solve this quiz question.

Adding it's image ->

[image]

I tried by finding numbers in the sentences but couldn't find and I think that's a wrong approach.

Can anyone please tell how to solve this question.

Answer is B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers are spelled out in each phrase.  The first has eleven (Tins*eleven*t), the second nine.  Look for the other two.  There is no excuse for this being called mathematics.

Comment: 8, 10 (4,2,1,3)

Comment: @Ross , ya it's more suitable for puzzling stackexchange.